# OneDrive - ETag does not match current item's value

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, etag, microsoft-graph-files

Monday: My OneDrive integration has suddenly stopped working today, yielding an ETag error. Note that I am not uploading/writing - simply reading. Here is the error from reading a directory. (no changes in user permission since it was working last night) Any idea what's causing it / how to fix?

```
POST ERROR: HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children {
  "error": {
    "code": "resourceModified",
    "message": "ETag does not match current item's value",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-06-22T20:29:07",
      "request-id": "{uuid}"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This error is usually because the resource being updated has been changed since the last time the caller read it, so it will cause an eTag mismatch, and a new Etag value must be generated. By comparing them, you can determine whether the two representations of the resource are the same.

Comment: The value of `{uuid}` will be helpful to take a closer look at what's causing your issue. Also, is this for a consumer or business account?